# Nested links in some posts

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

Some SE posts contain nested `<a>` elements in their HTML markup, which isn't valid HTML (at least according to W3 validator). One example is [here](https://superuser.com/a/706154/380375):

```
Homepage: <a href="http://rsync.samba.org/" rel="nofollow"><a href="http://rsync.samba.org/" rel="nofollow">http://rsync.samba.org/</a></a>
```

There are [21 such posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/332093/nested-links) on Super User, and probably proportionally more on Stack Overflow (the query takes too long).

I reproduced the creation of such links [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260027/259867). The input is valid HTML:

```
 I heard you like links to Stack Exchange, so... 
 <a href="http://stackexchange.com">http://stackexchange.com</a>
```

The output is invalid HTML:

```
<p>I heard you like links to Stack Exchange, so... 
<a href="http://stackexchange.com"><a href="http://stackexchange.com">http://stackexchange.com</a></a></p>
```

The input of this kind is possible if one copy-pastes a bare link (text content = href) from another document.

(Tagging as markdown-rendering since this is the output  of a Markdown renderer. Even though no Markdown is involved)